# Codec for video surveillance assuming non-changing scenes

Tags: video, codec

Are there video codecs, which automatically and effectively compress static scenes? For example, if we have the same room shown at the same light, this codec should produce zero or very low extra bytes.

Comment: All modern encoders do this - x264, x265, vp8/9..

Comment: Noise make sequence of frames slightly different and non zero comprssion. 3d (2d+temporal) noise reduction before compression may be good idea.